# can i use plone workflow to manage autocad related drawings?

Tags: python, plone

How can I use Plone 4.1.4 to manage autocad drawings with different roles like architect, sr.architect, Project Manager, accounts manager(who manages the user accounts). I would first of all like to know whether Plone can be used to crease a workflow for uploaded autocad drawing files or for uploaded files as such? Doubt arises due to certain plone documentation which say that plone By default, content types Image and File have no workflow.
I wish to track the comments and changes made by the different user roles to the drawing files as well provide a lock i.e iterate through the working copy of the drawing files that have been uploaded. Can anyone suggest the best approach to this project using Plone?

Comment: You can see all content types workflow settings in portal_workflow via ZMI. As Laurence says, you can add a new type, then apply needed workflow for it.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the workflow used for File objects, or indeed copy the File type in portal_types to a a new Drawing type and change the workflow for that new type if you want to treat them differently to standard files in your CMS.